# coldfusion 10 and mysql - problems decrypting previously stored data

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, aes, coldfusion-10

I'm moving a site from CF8 to CF10 and one of the problems that has come up is retrieving data storied in mysql using aes_encrypt in mysql.  The column is blob.  When I access the CFC that retrieves the decrypted string I'm getting back a binary object with an error:

```
ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings.
```

On the CF8 system I could just output with:

```
<cfoutput>#qryResult.decryptedString#</cfoutput>
```

Under CF10, I have to wrap it in a toString()

```
<cfoutput>#toString(qryResult.decryptedString)#</cfoutput>
```

I don't know if this is a CF, MySQL or driver issue, and the best way to solve it, or if I need to take another step in converting this site over.  In other words is "toString()" the correct solution or is there a database parameter that can be put into the connect string to keep things as they were?

Comment: It would help to see the code or query that generates `qryResult.decryptedString`. Also, what version of MySQL and driver are you using? Assuming the CF code has *not* changed, it is likely a driver issue. I have had MySQL return binary instead of a string sometimes (not specific to encryption). Usually when implicit casting is involved.

Comment: a simple test query fails as well:  SELECT AES_DECRYPT(sec_blob,'myreallysecurekey') AS decryptedString WHERE ...etc.  The new server is 5.5.28 and the old is 5.0.45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a few tests with ColdFusion 8 and 10 (against the same database) and got similar results. The decrypted result was returned as a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) in ColdFusion 8 (and in MySQL), but as binary in ColdFusion 10.  So I suspect it is a driver bug, or possibly a deliberate change (I am not sure).

**Test Query**

```
    <cfquery name="qTest" datasource="mySQL51">
        SELECT AES_DECRYPT(encryptedColumn, 'xxxxxxx') AS DecryptedResult
        FROM   test
        WHERE  ID = 1
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput>
        class name = #qTest.decryptedResult[1].getClass().name#
    </cfoutput>
```

**Results**

```
    ColdFusion  8  / class name = java.lang.String 
    ColdFusion 10  / class name = [B   (ie binary/byte array)
```

---

Other than testing different drivers, the simplest solution is to convert the value to a string as you are doing now. You can either do the conversion in SQL:

```
   SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(encryptedColumn, 'xxx') AS CHAR) AS DecryptedResult
```

.. or in CF code. Just be sure to specify an encoding like UTF-8

```
  <!--- if result is binary, convert it to a string first --->
  <cfif IsBinary( qTest.decryptedResult )>
      <cfset decryptedString = charsetEncode( qTest.decryptedResult, "utf-8" )>
  </cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh!  It's only in a few places in our existing app so I added the toString() on my output where needed.  Any advantage / disadvantage in doing that vs. your charsetEncode()?  The input on this field is limited to numeric only (like a credit card number, but it's not a card number).

Comment: The one difference I am aware of is that `toString` uses the encoding of the current page, if you do not specify one. That is not always desirable, so I prefer to specify it explicitly. Aside from that, I am not sure how much difference there is with simple strings. Just that [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f9e.html) recommend `charsetEncode` over `toString` for new apps.